# Which iPhone to buy for app testing

Tags: iphone, ios, testing

I am rather new to iOS development. I have previously developed several apps for Androud and i want to code them for iOS.
These apps will user CoreLocation, AVFoundation and such - mainly apps for music and localized events.
My question is: which iphone model should I buy to test my aps.
I am currently considering either 3GS or iPhone4. Some friends that develop for iOS recommended to buy 3GS - it can run iOS6 and packs all the necessary features - gps, accelerometer, compass.

Comment: First, I don't think this question is suited for StackOverflow. Please look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Second, my asnwer, look at the answer block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually go for iPhone 4 for the following reasons:

- Retina screen which is found in many other devices (iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, 2 generations of iPod Touch), which is critical to verifying your interface looks sane
- iPhone 4 is more likely to support future versions of iOS. Having a HUGE adoption rate it might be very critical for live apps (when you run into a bug and have to reproduce it)
- If I'm not mistaken, multitasking is not supported by 3gs, which also might cause some bugs.
- The amount of users with iPhone 4 devices is quite big according to many surveys and will (if have not already) outgrow 3gs owners.
- iPhone 4 is just so much better :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't always buy the weakest possible model out of all options. The 3GS can run iOS 6, and it has all the "core" features, yes, but there's no signs of life for it in the near future. You may start developing apps tomorrow, the day after iOS 7 gets released, and it turns out there's no support for the iPhone 3GS.

If you're really serious about it you should at least get an iPhone 4S, or at the very very least, an iPhone 4. If you buy an iPhone 3GS it may be a waste of money in the long run.

If that doesn't cut it for you, an iPod Touch 5 or iPod Touch 4 will be great for development with a few limitations, but both of them will be supported for a longer time than the 3GS (My guess).

Comment: The 3GS is best for testing that yr App will run with only 256MB of memory. The later phones have 512MB+. The 3GS also tests non retina screen usage. Later phones have the hi-res screen.

Answer (score 0):

The more devices available to you the better. Your friends suggestion of a 3GS might be a bit too old, but if your app runs well on hardware that is going on 4 years old then you will be sure that it'll be well optomized for the iPhone 5 and beyond.

Having an iPhone 5 available would be very useful for testing the different aspect ratio and how it affects your apps as well. The iPhone 5 will also future proof you for a bit as the 3GS will likely not support iOS7.

So basically, if can afford to get an old used iPhone 3GS and an iPhone 5 (or equivilent generation of iPod Touch), I'd get both.

Answer (score 0):

It is upto you to decide what phone best works with you.

Do you want to develop for iPhone 3GS? Most likely in the next revision of the iPhone, Apple will drop support for 3GS. So to future-proof yourself a bit, I would go with 4s. This way you can have 2 years worth of development time with the device and also work on stuff which is not available on the 3GS.

Also 3GS may have some hardware missing which is found on the 4S (I don't have the exact list at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would choose a 3GS and an iPhone 4+ as they are quite different.

The 3GS is best for testing that yr App will run with only 256MB of memory. The later phones have 512MB+. The 3GS also tests non retina screen usage. Later phones have the hi-res screen.

Without both types you can't truly test them. The simulator helps but isn't a 100% test.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator from Keynote works wonders and emulates over 2200 devices.

http://mite.keynote.com/